# Is it possible to handle changes in asp:Table without using javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an `asp:Table` which is filled (image, text and checkboxes) from my database dynamically. I want to change the checkboxes check state but I can't send changes into aspx.cs class file. So, I can' t save the changes into database.

I don' t know javascript so I am stuck now. Is it possible to handle changes without using javascript?

Here is my table:

```html
<asp:Table ID="DefaultTable" runat="server">
    <asp:TableHeaderRow ID="tableHeaderID" TableSection="TableHeader">
        <asp:TableHeaderCell>ID</asp:TableHeaderCell>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell>Image</asp:TableHeaderCell>
        <asp:TableHeaderCell>Checkbox</asp:TableHeaderCell> 
    </asp:TableHeaderRow>
</asp:Table>
```

Comment: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Save-Insert-CheckBox-value-to-Database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: thanks for fast answer but I couldn' t understand one point. How can i insert button in dynamically created table.

<asp:Table ID="DefaultTable" >
    <asp:TableHeaderRow ID="tableID" TableSection="TableHeader">
        <asp:TableHeaderCell>ID</asp:TableHeaderCell>
    </asp:TableHeaderRow>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" x"></asp:Button>
</asp:Table> 
I tried this but get "Error 7 Literal content ('</asp:Button>') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCellCollection'. E:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebSite3\Default.aspx"

Comment: have you tried using asp:GridView? You can set the GridView datasource to be your database table. You can also use <ItemTemplate> in the <TemplateField> of the GridView to dynamically add controls and create a CheckedChanged method or OnClick method.